# Polymer build compress

Tags: ecmascript-6, polymer, web-component

I am generating a component application in Polymer .. as a template I used the following: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/start-polymer3. Everything works excellent, I uploaded it to firebase, the point is that I want to make 'polymer build' generate the structure of folders: build / s6-unbundled, along with other folders like node_modules and my custom script, if you know some way to compress all the scripts generated in the build into a single file. Since the components I want to insert in third-party sites but I want to load only one js file and not have to load all what the polymer generates. I've done this with vue-custom.component but I do not know how to Polymer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for the [build](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli-commands#build) command. It lists all the possible options for bundling and minifying your code. It also lists some existing presets for you to use.